# How to convert UDP DatagramSocket to Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, udp, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm new about Spring Integration, and I'm a little confusing about how to implements a request-response UDP using Spring Integration.

I'm usigin java17 and spring-boot 3.1.

I need to send one UDP message to a external System (in specific a PLC) and wait a response from it.
I would like to convert this code

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1000]; // Max numeber of byte when I read a PLC Omron
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        try (DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket()) {
//cmd - byte[] cmd
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(cmd, cmd.length, getIpAddress(), getPort());
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
            // wait response
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);// blocking with timeout
            
        }
```

into Spring Integration approach ( if it is possible )

I have tried to use

```
UnicastSendingMessageHandler adapter = new UnicastSendingMessageHandler(getHost(), getPort());
unicastSendingMessageHandler.handleMessage(MessageBuilder.withPayload(messageToSend).build());
```

getHost, getPort and messageToSend can be changing. They depend on how many different system I need to contact.

In this way I send the message to the system but, I don't know what I need to do to wait the response.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no Outbound Gateway implementation for UDP: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/5796.

You can use two channel adapters combination and specify a `UnicastSendingMessageHandler.socketExpression` for `UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter.getSocket()`.

Then you can use a `BarrierMessageHandler` to correlate request and reply. The server side must ensure to transfer a correlation data back to the reply.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#udp-adapters

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#barrier

I understand that it is much involved, but there is no way right now to easy implement a gateway solution in Spring Integration.

Comment: Thanks for the response Artem.
It doesn't seems a simple work to do, also because we need to generate N UDP channels, one for each PLC machine that we will configure on our application
We will think if it is better to develop a new connection, as you mentioned, or continuing to use the old one